# Why does Url.Action returns null during UnitTesting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, url, mocking

I'm trying to make a Unit Test which also includes Moq Version 4.5.9.
Simply put, I only want to get the Url.Action just like in Mvc Controllers.
Here is what I've done:

```
var Cntrlr = new ErrorController();
var HttpCnt = new Mock<HttpContextHelper>(Utility.FakeHttpContext);
var UrlHelperMock = new Mock<UrlHelper>(HttpCnt.Object.ContextRequest.RequestContext);

Cntrlr.Url = UrlHelperMock.Object;
var RedirectUrl = Cntrlr.Url.Action("Index", "Error", new { errorName = "NotSupport" });
```

Also, if you must know, FakeHttpContext is like this:

```
public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext
{
    get
    {
        var HttpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", ""); 
        var StringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var HttpResponse = new HttpResponse(StringWriter);
        var HttpContext = new HttpContext(HttpRequest, HttpResponse);
        var SessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", 
            new SessionStateItemCollection(),
            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect, 
            SessionStateMode.InProc, false);
        HttpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState)
            .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) }, null)
            .Invoke(new object[] { SessionContainer });
        return HttpContext;
    }
}
```

Why RedirectUrl is returning Null? Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2012/05/04/testing-url-helper-within-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc/).

```
public static class AutoMockContainer
{
    public static AutoMock Create()
    {
        var autoMock = new AutoMock();

        var httpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();
        autoMock.Provide(httpContext);

        var server = Substitute.For<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        httpContext.Server.Returns(server);

        var request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestBase>();
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        request.Params.Returns(parameters);
        var formParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        request.Form.Returns(formParameters);
        var qsParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        request.QueryString.Returns(qsParameters);
        var headers = new NameValueCollection();
        headers.Add("Host", "localhost");
        request.Headers.Returns(headers);
        request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Returns("~/");
        request.ApplicationPath.Returns("/");
        request.Url.Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/"));
        request.Cookies.Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
        request.ServerVariables.Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        autoMock.Provide(request);
        httpContext.Request.Returns(request);

        var response = Substitute.For<HttpResponseBase>();
        response.Cookies.Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
        response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(a => a.Arg<string>());
        autoMock.Provide(response);
        httpContext.Response.Returns(response);

        var routeData = new RouteData();

        var requestContext = Substitute.For<RequestContext>();
        requestContext.RouteData = routeData;
        requestContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
        autoMock.Provide(requestContext);

        var actionExecutingContext = Substitute.For<ActionExecutingContext>();
        actionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Returns(httpContext);
        actionExecutingContext.RouteData.Returns(routeData);
        actionExecutingContext.RequestContext = requestContext;
        autoMock.Provide(actionExecutingContext);

        var actionExecutedContext = Substitute.For<ActionExecutedContext>();
        actionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Returns(httpContext);
        actionExecutedContext.RouteData.Returns(routeData);
        actionExecutedContext.RequestContext = requestContext;
        autoMock.Provide(actionExecutedContext);

        var controller = Substitute.For<ControllerBase>();
        autoMock.Provide(controller);
        actionExecutingContext.Controller.Returns(controller);

        var controllerContext = Substitute.For<ControllerContext>();
        controllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
        controllerContext.RouteData = routeData;
        controllerContext.RequestContext = requestContext;
        controllerContext.Controller = controller;
        autoMock.Provide(controllerContext);
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

        var iView = Substitute.For<IView>();
        autoMock.Provide(iView);

        var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary();
        autoMock.Provide(viewDataDictionary);

        var iViewDataContainer = Substitute.For<IViewDataContainer>();
        iViewDataContainer.ViewData.Returns(viewDataDictionary);
        autoMock.Provide(iViewDataContainer);

        var textWriter = Substitute.For<TextWriter>();
        autoMock.Provide(textWriter);

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, iView, viewDataDictionary, new TempDataDictionary(), textWriter)
        {
            HttpContext = httpContext,
            RouteData = routeData,
            RequestContext = requestContext,
            Controller = controller
        };
        autoMock.Provide(viewContext);

        return autoMock;
    }

    public static T GetController<T>(this AutoMock autoMock) where T : Controller
    {
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        MyApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        var controller = autoMock.Resolve<T>();
        controller.ControllerContext = autoMock.Resolve<ControllerContext>();
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(autoMock.Resolve<RequestContext>(), routes);
        return controller;
    }
}
```

To initilize

```
var autoMock = AutoMockContainer.Create();
var controller = autoMock.GetController<HomeController>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `Url.Action` returns `null` in this case is because you have mocked the `UrlHelper`, but you have not defined what is supposed to happen when your code calls the `UrlHelper.Action` method of your mock.

### Mocking `Url.Action` in MVC 5

```
var Cntrlr = new ErrorController();
var UrlHelperMock = new Mock<UrlHelper>();
UrlHelperMock
    .Setup(x => x.Action(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns("/Error/Index/NotSupport");

Cntrlr.Url = UrlHelperMock.Object;
var RedirectUrl = Cntrlr.Url.Action("Index", "Error", new { errorName = "NotSupport" });
```

The idea is that you should be testing *your* code under specific conditions, and not be concerned with whether you are calling a real or a fake `Url.Action` behind the scenes. You should only mock exactly the bare minimum to make the test work, so creating a fake `HttpContext` or `RequestContext` in this case is overkill.

> **NOTE:** You should assume that the MVC framework already has tests to ensure that `Url.Action` functions. And, you should [unit test your routes](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/testing-routing-and-url-generation-in-aspnet-mvc.html) which will ensure `Url.Action` will return the correct URL in all cases. But that is a separate concern from this unit test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.. But in the line you have added I'm getting `Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Action(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Object>())` error. Do you have any idea about this as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My code is not in VB. I dont know why the error says `virtual (overridable in VB)` or VB is VB.net for that matter.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? This works fine with MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: :net 4.0 with VS 2012

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didnt write that.. .NET 4.0 - MVC 4 - VS 2012

Comment: Okay, this apparently won't work for MVC < 5. The methods were marked virtual in MVC 5, so it works with MVC 5 but not MVC 4. There is an [alternate method here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678045/181087) that might work for you.

Comment: In fact I have seen the page you send and because of that I was able to go up to this point. But stuck here.

Comment: Thank you nightowl for your afford. May be I'll upgrade to MVC 5 but since this is a large project it might cause some other problems.

Comment: An alternative to upgrading to MVC 5 may be to inject the URL helper and call `this.urlHelper.Action` rather than calling `this.Url.Action` inside your action method. [Here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Mvc/IUrlHelper.cs) and [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Mvc/UrlHelperAdapter.cs)  are an interface and adapter for UrlHelper. Just accept `IUrlHelper` in your controller constructor, inject the `UrlHelperAdapter` in your live app..

Comment: and mock `IUrlHelper` for your tests exactly as I have shown above. And of course change all references from `this.Url...` in your controller to `this.urlHelper...` (the class-level variable that holds `IUrlHelper` instance).